# Why doesn't my ReceiveMessage.java class set SMS body to my textview?

Tags: java, android, textview, sms

I have a button in an activity. By clicking on it an SMS with a predefined body and phone address is sent, then a reply SMS including a code is automatically sent to my mobile phone . I need to receive the code and set it to my textview. How can I solve it? I have two activities : MainActivity and MessageReceiver.

```
    //MessageReceiver.java
    public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] messages;
        String str = "";

        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            messages = new SmsMessage[pdus != null ? pdus.length : 0];
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) (pdus != null ? pdus[i] : null));
                str += messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += ":";
                str += messages[i].getMessageBody();
                str += "\n";
            }
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
            broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECIEVED_ACTION");
            broadcastIntent.putExtra("message", str);
            context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);}}}
```

---

```
     //MainActivity.java
     private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            TextView chargeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chargeText);
            Log.d("myTag", "is chargeText null? : " + (chargeText==null));
            Log.d("myTag", "The text is: " + (intent.getExtras().getString("message")));
            chargeText.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("message"));
        }
    };

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
 button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

 button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String mymsg = "CMDACC_1234";
                String thenumber = "09380638202";
                SendChargeMessage(thenumber, mymsg);
            }
        });}

    public void SendChargeMessage(String thenumber, String mymsg) {
        String SENT = "Message sent";
        String DELIVERED = "Message delivered";
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        Context curContext = this.getApplicationContext();
        PendingIntent sentPending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(curContext,
                0, new Intent("SENT"), 0);
        curContext.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sent.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Sent: Generic failure.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Sent: No service (possibly, no SIM-card).",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Sent: Null PDU.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Sent: Radio off (possibly, Airplane mode enabled in Settings).",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter("SENT"));

        PendingIntent deliveredPending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(curContext,
                0, new Intent("DELIVERED"), 0);

        curContext.registerReceiver(
                new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                        switch (getResultCode()) {
                            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Delivered.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Delivered: Canceled.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }, new IntentFilter("DELIVERED"));

        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

        if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY) &&
                !pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY_CDMA)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, your device probably can't send SMS...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            smsManager.sendTextMessage("09380638202", null, "CMDACC_1234", sentPendin

g, deliveredPending);
                //chargeText.setText(SMSBody1);
            }
        }

///Edited

 @Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter intentFilter;
    intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");

    BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            TextView chargeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chargeText);
            Log.d("myTag", "is chargeText null? : " + (chargeText==null));

            Log.d("myTag", "The text is: " + (intent.getExtras().getString("message")));

            String text = intent.getExtras().getString("message").toString(); // let's try this with toString() so we are very explicit about it

            Log.d("myTag", "The converted text is: " + text);

            chargeText.setText(text);
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(intentReceiver , intentFilter);

} }
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dearzeinab.emaapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.dearzeinab.emaapplication.MessageReceiver" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register your receiver.

Like so:

```
getActivity().registerReceiver(intentReceiver, new IntentFilter("SMS_RECIEVED_ACTION"));
```

Only then it will work.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Here's how it should look in your code:

```
//MainActivity.java
    private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver; // do not set it up here. We'll set it and register it onCreate(), but we'll keep it here so it stays on scope of every other function
    private IntentFilter intentFilter; // same for the filter

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // We'll set up the receiver here, after the activity starts
        intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                TextView chargeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chargeText);
                Log.d("myTag", "is chargeText null? : " + (chargeText==null));

                Log.d("myTag", "The text is: " + (intent.getExtras().getString("message")));

                String text = intent.getExtras().getString("message").toString(); // let's try this with toString() so we are very explicit about it

                Log.d("myTag", "The converted text is: " + text);

                chargeText.setText(text);
            }
        };

        // then, we'll create the filter
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();

        intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String mymsg = "CMDACC_1234";
                String thenumber = "09380638202";
                SendChargeMessage(thenumber, mymsg);
            }
        });

        registerReceiver(intentReceiver , intentFilter); // registering
    }

    public void SendChargeMessage(String thenumber, String mymsg) {
        String SENT = "Message sent";
        String DELIVERED = "Message delivered";
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        Context curContext = this.getApplicationContext();
        PendingIntent sentPending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(curContext, // Are you sure you want to create a new intent here?
                0, new Intent("SENT"), 0);
        curContext.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() { // and are you sure this is supposed to be a new receiver as well? Are you registering it like we did with iontentReceiver?
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sent.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Sent: Generic failure.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Sent: No service (possibly, no SIM-card).",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Sent: Null PDU.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Sent: Radio off (possibly, Airplane mode enabled in Settings).",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter("SENT"));

        PendingIntent deliveredPending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(curContext, 
                0, new Intent("DELIVERED"), 0);

        curContext.registerReceiver( 
                new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                        switch (getResultCode()) {
                            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Delivered.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Delivered: Canceled.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }, new IntentFilter("DELIVERED"));

        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

        if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY) &&
                !pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY_CDMA)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, your device probably can't send SMS...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            smsManager.sendTextMessage("09380638202", null, "CMDACC_1234", sentPending, deliveredPending);
            //chargeText.setText(SMSBody1);
        }
    }
```

What I saw in your code:

- You were registering a receiver before onStart(). This receiver was in scope for every single method. But it was not registered.
- You were creating a new receiver in onResume(), with the same name as the previous one (broadcastReceiver). You were registering this one properly, but it was outside of scope for every function.
- This means you were trying to access an unregistered receiver, and you were registering a receiver with the same name but outside of scope.

If this doesn't work, at least you'll be one step closer of making it work ;)

If you want my opinion, you could:

- Study scope and how it works in Object Oriented Programming;
- Study receivers, intents and how to register them.

Hope it helps.
Good luck mate.

Comment: Thanks. No. It didn't work. I receive the SMS and its body is shown as a toast, but it has not been set in the textview.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I thought your problem was receiving the message, not setting it on the TextView. When you receive the message, check for nulls and the text itself. I'll update my post so you can see how.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But problem has not been solved yet. I edited my question and added the whole code that I use. Would you please see it.

Comment: After looking at your code, I think you are defining the intentFilter after registering the receiver. So the receiver is being registered with a null intentFilter. Can you try putting them in the correct order, please? Just to test this idea. Can you try to put everything (creating the intentFilter, creating and registering the receiver) in onResume()?

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that I should do it like the edited code in onResume()?

Comment: Exactly (but you should put super.onResume() before everything :) ). Did it work?

Comment: Well? How was it? Look mate, if you want help, you should mark correct answers as correct. Else, people will just stop helping you.

Comment: I really appreciate your help,I followed your advices but my problem has not been solved yet.II can't vote anyone because my reputation is under 15.

Comment: That's different :p I just assumed you got your answer and moved on. But if your problem has not been solved yet, I can still try to help you. What do you get from your debug logs?

Comment: I send the SMS to the destination by clicking on the button, and then receive the reply SMS from the destination. But the body of the received SMS is not shown in the textview.

Comment: I updated my answer again. Let me know what you got in "The converted text is: " + text.

Comment: No difference, Sir.

Comment: I updated my code as you said...please look at it to see if I got your point correctly

Comment: Yes. But it is not clear to me if you get the message you want in your console or not. What does your debug console say? Does it print the expected message?

Comment: You don't have the actual message text in your toasts. All you have is predefined messages. But I'm not asking about the toasts. I'm asking about the console. On the bottom options you have "6. Logcat". Click it. That's your console. Does it print "The converted text is: [the actual text of the message you want to receive]" ?

Comment: Ok. Perfect. Now we know the problem is receiving the text. How are your permissions? Do you have sms permissions set in the manifest? What version of android are you using? Because permissions are managed ina  different way for android 6 and above.

Comment: Thanks:) I added the manifest.xml to my question, you can see it in the Question part.  My android version is 5.0.2

Comment: Yeah, you do need permissions for everything in Android. Did it work?

Comment: No,  It didn't work. I edited my question and added the manifest that I used for my application. Does My manifest.xml have problem?

Comment: No. Everything looks correct. Sadly, I don't know how to help you after all. Sorry. You should unmark my answer as the correct one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Would you please take a look at my edited code to see if something is wrong or not for the last time?

Comment: Sure. I saw a problem in your code. I'll update my post in a while.

Answer (score -1):

Use Below code in your receiver

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (Object aPdusObj : pdusObj) {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) aPdusObj);
                    String senderAddress = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.d(TAG, "Received SMS: " + message + ", Sender: " + senderAddress);

                    // if the SMS is not from our gateway, ignore the message
                    if (!senderAddress.toLowerCase().contains(GlobalApplication.SMS_ORIGIN.toLowerCase())) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // verification code from sms
                    String verificationCode = getVerificationCode(message);

                    Log.d(TAG, "OTP received: " + verificationCode);

                    mListener.otpReceived(verificationCode);

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Getting the OTP from sms message body
     * ':' is the separator of OTP from the message
     *
     * @param message
     * @return
     */
    private String getVerificationCode(String message) {
        String str_msg = message.replace("Dear Customer,","");
        str_msg = str_msg.replace("is your one time password (OTP). Please enter the OTP to proceed.","");
        str_msg = str_msg.replace("Thank you,","");
        str_msg = str_msg.replace("ChannelPaisa","");
        str_msg = str_msg.replace("\n","");

        str_msg= str_msg.trim().toString();

        return str_msg;
    }
```